# How do I show sticky posts on a static front page that also contains content?

Tags: theme-development, frontpage, sticky-post

In my theme, I'm using `front-page.php` for the static front page. I'm also using a page to store the content on the static front page. The `front-page.php` file is set up to show the content from that page.

However, in the `front-page.php` file, I also want to show all of my blog's sticky posts below that content. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
if ( !empty( $sticky ) ) {  // don't show anything if there are no sticky posts
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,  // show all sticky posts
        'post__in'  => $sticky,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display your sticky post here (however you like to do it)
    }
}
```

You should place this in your `front-page.php` file. It will select all sticky posts and show them.

Comment: Make sure to also add a `wp_reset_postdata();` after your if statement to reset the `$post` global to the main query.